# If $a$ and $b$ are elements of the image of $f(A)$, then $[a,b]$ is a subset of $f(A)$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f:A\to\mathbb R$ be a continuous function. If the numbers $2$ and $3$ are elements of the image $f(A)$, then the interval $[2,3]$ is a subset of  $f(A)$.
Intuitively I think it's true, and I couldn't find any counterexamples.

I have a proof using the intermediate value theorem but I don't know if it's correct.
Supposed $f(a)=2$ and $f(b)=3$, and since $f$ is continuous, for any number $d$ between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$, which is the interval $(2,3)$, there exists $c\in [a,b]$ such that $f(c)=d$. So $[2,3]$ is a subset of $f(A)$.

Comment: That's perfectly correct. Actually the *Intermediate value theorem*  is equivalent with: for a continuous function $f$, the image of an interval is an interval.

Comment: Actually, this is only true if A is connected, so @bernard is right about intervals to intervals, but not every subspace is connected.

Answer (score 2):

Actually I think it is false. Take $A = (-\infty, 2]\cup[3,\infty)$ and $f(x) = x$. Clearly $f$ is continuous (assuming $\mathbb{R}$ has the standard topology and $A$ has the subspace topology) but $(2,3)$ isn't part of the image.

Comment: but the domain not including $(2,3)$ doesn't mean the image doesn't include $(2,3)$

Comment: $a,b$ don't have to be in $(2,3)$ for $f(a)=2$ and $f(b)=3$, right?

Comment: Using my previous example, the preimage of $2.5$ would be $2.5$ since $f$ works as the identity. But $2.5\notin A$. Hence $2.5\notin f(A)$

Comment: In general, if $f:A\rightarrow B$ is a function, then
$f(A) = \{b\in B : \exists \; a\in A \;\;s.t.\;\; f(a) = b\} = \{f(a): a\in A\}$

Comment: Why does $f$ have to work as the identity?

Comment: Take $i$ the identity function in the real line. Then you can say that $i_{|A}=f$, where $_{|A}$ denotes restricting the domain of a function to the set $A$

Comment: but wouldn't that function be discontinuous in $(2,3)$?

Comment: There are two ways of looking at it:

-> It would certainly be discontinuous if the domain of $f$ happened to be $\mathbb R$ since for example, $f$ is not defined in 2.5. But 2.5 isn't part of my domain. $f$ is continuous when we consider any element in the domain.

-> A basic topological result is that a continuous function will remain continuous when its domain is restricted/shrank. As I noted in my previous comment, in this case we take a continuous function in $\mathbb R$ which happens to be the identity and shrink its domain to something that excludes $(2,3)$